# Postgres partition pruning with text prefix matching

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a table where the natural identifier is a text like this: `AB-C123456E-F`, which is my primary key.
The table is approaching 200 million rows, and so to get better performance on the unique constraint I've split it up into partitions by range:

```sql
CREATE TABLE documents (
    doc_number text PRIMARY KEY,
    doc_data bytea,
    doc_data_sha256 bytea
) PARTITION BY RANGE (doc_number text_pattern_ops);

CREATE TABLE documents_a_abc123z PARTITION OF documents FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO ('AB-C123z');
CREATE TABLE documents_abc124_def456z PARTITION OF documents FOR VALUES FROM ('AB-C124') TO ('DE-F456z');
...
```

These rows are queried by either equality or prefix match of the document number, and while partition pruning works as expected with an equality match, I can't get Postgres to do pruning for a prefix match. I've tried using `SELECT * FROM documents WHERE doc_number LIKE 'AB-C12345%'` and `SELECT * FROM documents WHERE starts_with(doc_number, 'AB-C12345')`.

*Is there a way I can get partition pruning over range partitions with a text prefix?*

Comment: You probably need `where doc_number >= '...'  and doc_number < '...'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the suggestion. I've just tried and got no luck, it still visits every partition.

Comment: It might be using runtime pruning (instead of plan time pruning) which is only visible if you do `explain (analyze)`

Comment: Another option might be to use `PARTITION BY RANGE (left(doc_number, 7)` and then use  `left(doc_number,7) = 'AB-C123'` in addition to the actual `LIKE` condition in the query. However you can no longer defined `doc_number` as the primary key

Answer (score 0):

You could create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
   doc_number varchar(10) COLLATE "C" NOT NULL,
   num_prefix varchar(7) COLLATE "C" NOT NULL,
   ...,0
   PRIMARY KEY (doc_number, num_prefix)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (num_prefix);
```

Then write a `BEFORE` trigger that makes sure that `num_prefix` is always the prefix of `doc_number` (using a generated column is not allowed for the partitioning key):

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_id_part() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.num_prefix := left(NEW.doc_number, 7);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER set_id_part BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON documents
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION set_id_part();
```

The primary key has to contain the partitioning key in a partitioned table, but that does not detract from the uniqueness of `doc_number` (only the index is somewhat larger).

Now, to get partition pruning, all you have to do is add an additional expression to the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM documents
WHERE doc_number LIKE 'AB-C12345%'
  AND num_prefix = 'AB-C12345';
```

Not perfect, but I guess that's the best you can get.